# bash functions arguments in single quotes

Tags: bash

I am trying to pass 2 arguments into the following bash function $1 and $2. If I just echo the below statement it seems to just output $1 and $2. I need to have the arguments in single quotes for the function to work correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
function mysql_diff()
{
    java -jar mysql-diff.jar 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/$1?user=root&password=PASSWORD' 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/$2?user=root&password=PASSWORD'
}
```

Comment: Variable expansion won't happen within single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need the arguments to be enclosed in single quotes.  To achieve that, enclose everything in double quotes:

```
function mysql_diff()
{
    java -jar mysql-diff.jar "'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/$1?user=root&password=PASSWORD'" "'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/$2?user=root&password=PASSWORD'"
}
```

This would not prevent variable expansion and would also result in the arguments being enclosed in single quotes.